# RMI IIOP client object as callback

Tags: java, rmi, iiop

I'm trying to build rmi-iiop application (very simple chat).
I need server to be able to communicate with client so my thinking was to create interface of connected user:

```
public interface UserInterface extends Remote { 
    public void receiveMessage(String message) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Then on client side create User class with methods server can execute('receiveMessage'):

```
public class User extends PortableRemoteObject implements UserInterface {

    protected User() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(String message) throws RemoteException {
        client.addMessageToGUI();
    }
}
```

I use `rmic -iiop Chat User` which generates `_Chat_Tie.class _ChatInterface_Stub.class _User_Tie.class _UserInterface_Stub.class`

After placing all files on server side and client side and running the application I get following error:
`java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found: User_Stub; nested exception is:`

I guess the difference here is that Chat class is created on server and then client uses it using interface (which works fine), but user class has to be created on client side, so client works partly as a server.

My question is similar to [Java RMI - Making the client a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808392/java-rmi-making-the-client-a-server)
but for rmi-ioop implementation.

So in to words - how can I send local object reference to server so it could perform operations on it?

Thanks!
Leonty

Comment: Can thing called 'POA'(Portable Object Adapter) which is a part of CORBA standard have to do with what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: As of Java 5.0, you no longer require `rmic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing is "Tie" class on client side (_User_Tie.class). Usually it's not needed but in case when object is created on client side - I needed to supply it also.

Hope it saves some time for someone else in a future :)

Answer (score 0):

you create a server interface like:

```
public interface ChatServer extends Remote {
  public void registerUser(UserInterface user) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how it's done on server side.
The problem however is on the client when trying to create User object which I want to pass to the server.